# Change Content of Rad SideDrawer (was 'Second (third,...) Side Drawer'

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

Should be quite simple, but if I ask it here, perhaps others can use.

How to add a second side drawer?

I've copied `DrawerContent.vue` to `DrawerContentL2.vue`, and modified the contents.

And added

```
import DrawerContentL2 from "./components/DrawerContentL2";
```

to my app.js

And the original app.js looks like

```
new Vue({
     render (h) {
        return h(
          App,
          [
            h(DrawerContent, { slot: 'drawerContent' }),
            h(Twisty, { slot: 'mainContent' })   
    ]
        )
  }
  }).$start();
```

Now what?

Comment: Are you asking (based on your comments) how to change DrawerContent dynamically? Please add more details.

Comment: Yes. Or, rather, to use a different file for the content. Instead of filling the drawer with DrawerContent.vue, When user navigates page LevelTwo, drawer shows DrawerContentL2.vue. I knows it’s simple...

Comment: Within the DrawerContent use slot or simply v-if to render right component, switch the slot / variable when you reach second level?

Comment: Yep, that sounds right. I'm still not thinking reactively. (Guess that's what comes of trying to be a leader in the high school redesign movement while also learning to write native apps plus other work.)
Will let you know once I fix NativeScript Theme: Core V2 breaking my app)

Comment: What is the problem with Theme V2?

Comment: I just upgraded my app, and am not figuring out how to get it to work. Finally got it all to compile, but my app styling has fallen apart.

Comment: Amazing. Could not force Theme v2 to work. Tried to manually revert to 1.0.6. Still got "File to import not found or unreadable: nativescript-theme-core/scss/light" errors. 
Tried to roll back git commits. Still wouldn't work. I'm back to where I merely ran tns update from 6.2 to 6.3, and still cant get app to build and run as it did Wednesday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it.
Rather than trying to change the content of `slot: 'drawerContent'` from `DrawerContent.vue` to `DrawerContentL2.vue`, I just put them in two different files, and used the main DrawerContent.vue to choose which one.

Thanks to Alligator.io for the tips on how. [Swappable Dynamic Components in Vue.js](https://alligator.io/vuejs/dynamic-components/)

The new DrawerContent.vue looks like:

```
<template>
    <component :is="dynamicComponent"></component>
</template>

<script>

import DrawerContentL1 from "./DrawerContentL1";
import DrawerContentL2 from "./DrawerContentL2";

export default {
  components: {
    DrawerContentL1,
    DrawerContentL2
  },
  computed: {
    dynamicComponent() {
      if(this.$store.state.currentLevel=="L1") {
        return 'DrawerContentL1';
      } else {
        return 'DrawerContentL2';
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And, of course, each component file must declare it's name:

```
export default {
        name: "DrawerContentL1",
        mounted() {
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For NativeScript UI RadSideDrawer you have to put the second one inside the root one's content.

Or, alternatively, you can use [nativescript-vue-multi-drawer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-vue-multi-drawer) by Igor Randjelovic, which was specifically written for multi drawer functionality.

Comment: sorry, didn't say that right: I just need the one drawer, only after the first 10 pages, I need to replace the contents (DrawerContent.vue) with different content (Drawercontent2.vue).
I have a the second file. I'm just not sure how to summon it when the user navigates to the new section.

Answer (score 0):

I tried what I thought @Manoj was suggesting here:

```
    new Vue({ 
    render (h) {
      return h(
        App,
        [
          h(v-if (store.state.currentLevel == "L1"){DrawerContent} v-else {DrawerContentL2}, { slot: 'drawerContent' }),
          h(Home, { slot: 'mainContent' }) 
        ]
      )
    }
  }).$start()
```

Or, alternatively,

```
new Vue({ 
render (h) {
  return h(
    App,
    [
      h(if (store.state.currentLevel == "L1"){DrawerContent} else {DrawerContentL2}, { slot: 'drawerContent' }),
      h(Home, { slot: 'mainContent' }) 
    ]
  )
}
```

}).$start()

Both drew an `unexpected token` error on the conditional.

Answer (score 0):

And, for fun, tried wrapping the whole thing in a conditional.

```
if(store.state.currentLevel == "L1"){ 
  new Vue({ 
    render (h) {
      return h(
        App,
        [
          h(DrawerContent, { slot: 'drawerContent' }),
          h(Home, { slot: 'mainContent' }) 
        ]
      )
    }
  }).$start() }
else { 
  new Vue({ 
    render (h) {
      return h(
        App,
        [
          h(DrawerContentL2, { slot: 'drawerContent' }),
          h(LevelTwo, { slot: 'mainContent' })
         ] 
      )
        }
        }).$start(); }
```

This compiles and runs, but only on the app launch. Changing `currentLevel` does not change the `drawercontent`.